# Where do I look for cron errors

Tags: cron

I have 2 cron jobs that were running fine but now stopped running. I looked through my crontab and everything looks OK. How can I tell if these jobs are running? is there a place where cron stores errors? Where do I look for cron specific errors, or even a record of the cron jobs that ran prior.

Comment: by default every cron job sends email to that user check them with mail command

Comment: This posting has an extensive Q&A that explains how to watch cron.log in real time on-screen:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/966194/16-04-how-do-i-make-cron-create-cron-log-and-monitor-it-in-real-time?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try directing the output to a log file.  Just make sure that it exists and is writable by whatever user the cronjob is running as.  (In my example, this would be cyphertite)

I also recommend running date somewhere at the beginning of your script so that you get the date in the log file.

```
 0 15 * * *    /home/andrew/daily-backup.sh >> /var/log/cyphertite.log
```

Additionally, cron logs are directed to /var/log/syslog if that helps

Comment: ...and can be extracted via `grep CRON /var/log/syslog`

Comment: I was looking for the location of the syslog

Comment: Note that Ubuntu jammy for example has not a "/var/log/syslog"